# phonegap build android => cant find apk with android 7.0.0

Tags: android, apk, phonegap

I tried to update android in an existing phonegap project, told me fetching 7.0.0 ... completed. when I list platforms, it told me 6.3.0 was installed. So I did

```
phonegap platform remove android
phonegap platform add android
```

and copied my jks into platforms/android again.

phonegap build android (--release) is both telling me:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android' ...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --no-telemetry'
```

But I cant find my outputs folder. Neither in platforms/android/build (I only have folder "android-profile" with a json and a rowproto file for every build) nor in platforms/android/app/build (there are folders "intermediate" and "generated"). I already searched for android-release-unsigned.apk and app-release-unigned.apk - nothing found. 
Anybody an idea where to search or find out why it isn't created although there are no errors? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Things I already tried:
-removing and adding android (7.0.0) again
-removing and adding android@6.3.0 (also replacing the android folder with content one week old)
-removing and adding android@7.1.0
-building a whole new project with phonegap desktop (creates folder "outputs" on build, but no apks)
I have no idea how to go on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found by adding "-d" to the build command. Then phonegap gives detailed information on build problems. In my case it could not find google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found that the output directory has been changed from `..platforms\android\build` to `..\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`

You could check the above directory.